# I have oil in my reservoir

Tags: oil

I have a 2004 buick park ave. I see oil in reservoir but not in the radiator .How can this happen where is the oil comeing?

Comment: you sure its oil?

Comment: Oil is less dense than water, so it floats to the top of the highest point of the system.

Comment: Does not mean its oil, many things float on water

Comment: What do you mean by "reservoir?" There are lots of containers under the hood that hold various liquids. A picture (you can attach it to your question using the "edit" button) would help.